# Proof of a point's existence in an open interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

[image]

Well let us begin consider a set $A$

$$A = \{a \le x \le b \space | \space f(x) > 0  \}$$

Lets take $\alpha = \sup A$ and $\beta = \inf A$

What we must do is prove that $\alpha = d$ and $\beta = c$

Because $f(x)$ is continous, there are obviously points $c, d \in [a, b]$ but we must prove the inequality. Lets solve $\alpha = d$ proof first.

Assume $\alpha < d$

Contradiction follows because $\alpha$ was the $\sup A$

Now all that is left is $\alpha \ge d$

I cannot prove that $\alpha > d$ because $\alpha = \sup S > x$ has to be true.

How can I prove there are such points?  I can **try continuity,**

$$|f(x) - f(b)| < \epsilon \implies |x - b| < \delta$$

$$\therefore b - \delta < x < b + \delta$$

Or do they want to assume that:

$$c, d \in [a, b]$$ already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your try has a little problem. Notice that for $f=\sin$ and $[a,b]=[0,4\pi]$, we have $A=[0,\pi]\cup[2\pi,3\pi]$, but then $\sup A=3\pi$ and $\inf A=0$; $f$ is not always positive on $(\beta,\alpha)$.

Focus on the existence of $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$, and let $$c=\sup\{a\le x<x_0\mid f(x)=0\}$$ and $$d=\inf\{x_0<x\le b\mid f(x)=0\}.$$ Now you can prove that $f$ is positive on $(c,d)$, using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How does the Intemediate Value theorem help here though?

Comment: If $f(x_1)\le0$ for some $x_1\in(x_0,d)$, by IVT, there is $x_2\in(x_0,x_1]$ such that $f(x_2)=0$ since $f(x_0)>0$. This contradicts with the definition of $d$. Do similarly with $c$.

Comment: But we must prove points $c, d$ exist. We cannot simply say "let.."

Comment: You might know that the $\sup$ and the $\inf$ of the nonempty set always exist. Fortunately, $a\in\{a\le x<x_0\mid f(x)=0\}\neq\emptyset$ and $b\in\{x_0<x\le b\mid f(x)=0\}\neq\emptyset$. Furthermore, to prove that $f(c)=f(d)=0$, use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I think this answer is better because you are following up on my questions! Why dont you define sets:

$$\alpha = \{a\le x<x_0\mid f(x)>0\}$$ and $$\beta = \{x_0<x\le b\mid f(x)>0\}.$$

Instead of 

$$\alpha = \{a\le x<x_0\mid f(x)=0\}$$ and $$\beta = \{x_0<x\le b\mid f(x)=0\}.$$

Why only $f(x) = 0$ and not $f(x) > 0$ also, how should I prove $f(c) = 0$ and also $f(d) = 0$? Should I try contradiction? **Below in my Attempt**:

Comment: Assuming $f(c) > 0$ then by continuity, $f(x) > 0$ for $|x - c| < \delta \implies c - \delta < x < c + \delta$

Because $c = \inf \alpha$ be have:

$$x > c > c - \delta$$ 

Nevermind, this is too difficult, what other choices?

Comment: For the 1st question, you get $\sup\alpha=\inf\beta=x_0$.

Comment: For the 2nd question, use the fact that since $c$ is the sup of $\alpha$, _for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ such that $f(x)=0$._

Now if $\color{red}{f(c)>0}$, there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $f$ is positive on $(c-\delta_0,c+\delta_0)$, a contradiction.

And if $\color{red}{f(c)<0}$, by IVT, there exists $x_1\in(c,x_0)$ such that $f(x_1)$, which again contradicts with the definition of $c$.

Comment: I think this is easy enough. But if you cannot agree, I can show you another one which uses the limit of a sequence.

Comment: The GreatSeo, how did you use the IVT in that just because $c = \sup \alpha$ there has to be an $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ such that $f(x) = 0$? How does the IVT support this?

Comment: To prove the fact you mentioned, IVT is not needed.

Comment: TheGreatSeo, lets see. for proving $f(x) > 0$ in $x \in (c, d)$ I will use suppose contradiction. Suppose $f(x) < 0$ then because $f(x_0) > 0$ this means, by IVT there must exist a point $x_1$ such that $a < x_1 < x_0$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$. But how is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

*There is no need to use the intermediate values theorem*. As $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $\eta >0$ such that for each $x\in ]x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta[ \cap [a,b]$ one has $ f(x_0) - \varepsilon  < f(x) < f(x_0) + \varepsilon$. Choose $\varepsilon$ equal to $\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$, which is strictly positive, by hypothesis on $f(x_0)$. Then for the associated $\eta >0$, for each $x\in ]x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta[$ one has $f(x_0) - \frac{f(x_0)}{2} < f(x) < f(x_0) + \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$, which *a fortiori* implies that $f(x) > f(x_0) - \frac{f(x_0)}{2} = \frac{f(x_0)}{2} > 0$. Now $]x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta[ \cap [a,b]$ is obvioulsy of the required form $]c,d[$ with $a\leq c < x_0 < d \leq b$, even if $x_0 \in \{a,b\}$. Now that you have such $c$ and $d$, you have to find others such that $f$ is zero on $c$ and $d$. For this, you can take inf and sup of set where $f$ is strictly positive. Try, and if you do not succeed, get back to me.

Comment: however, how do we conclude that $a \le c$? ?? This is the hard part. We have $x \in (x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta)$ such that $f(x) > 0$ so we let $c = x_0 - \eta$ and $d = x_0 + \eta$ then how do we say $a \le c$? Wont it be $a < c$?

Comment: please advice me

Comment: Note that with the first step of the proof I give, you have $c < d$ and in fact $f(c) > 0$ and $f(d) > 0$. (Because if could have used continuity expression with closed (instead of open) $\eta$-ball centered around $x_0$.) Now, if you take $c' =$ the infimum of $x$'s in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x') = 0$ and $d'$ the supremum, obviously $c' \leq c$ and $d' \geq d$, and as $c < d$, this implies that $c < d$. All of this conditional on the fact that $a < b$, which is not assumed, but which is obviously needed, and which I assumed earlier in my answer.

Comment: No but where does the $\le$ part come in for $a \le c$? Why is the $=$ a condition? Why not just $a < c$?

Comment: I almost know this, all I ask is a little help!

Comment: ... As $c$ is in $[a,b]$, you MUST have $c\geq a$, mustn't you ? I see you're already not at easy with $<, \geq$ "subtleties", so you should first work on this, and then try to tackl questions of the same kind you've asked. Unless it's going to be really difficult for you.

Comment: I know these. But $c \ge a$ means there is a possibility that $c = a$ which means that $x_0 - \delta = a$ which cannot be true.

Comment: After that the only part I am having trouble with is proving $f(c) = 0$ and $f(d) = 0$... should I try contradiction?

Comment: RObert, here is what I got. Assume $f(c) > 0$ then by Spivak laws, we have: $f(x_3) > 0$ for $|x - c| < \delta$ for some $\delta > 0$ This fact implies $\implies c - \delta < x_3 < c + \delta$ but because $c \inf \alpha$ we have: $x_3 \ge c$ but because $\delta > 0$ we have: $x_3 \ge c > c + \delta$ but this is a contradiction to the hypothesis of $f(c) > 0$. I defined $\alpha$ as: $\alpha = \{ a \le x_1 \ le x_0 \space | \space f(x_1) > 0  \}$ for all $x_1$ in $[a, x_0]$ where $c = x_0 + \delta < x_0$ **any thoughts on the correctness of this proof?**

Comment: $c$ and $d$ are limits of points at which $f$ is zero, and $f$ is cnntinuous, so that it must me also zero at $c$ and $d$ !

Comment: How do you **prove** that though?

Comment: Whatever construction of $\mathbf{R}$ you may use, the sup (resp. inf) of a set $A$ is limit of an increasing (resp. of an decreasing) sequence of points of $A$. In our case, $c$ (resp. $d$) is the sup (resp. the inf) of a set (not the same for $c$ and $d$) of point where $f$ is zero. Now, by the initial remark, $c$ and $c$ are limits of sequences of points at which $f$ is zero. Then, by the continuity of $f$, $f(c)$ and $f(d)$ are zero.

Comment: Robert, So you are saying $c \to a$ and $d \to b$ ?? But how to prove this rigorously?

Comment: Please Robert Green,  I really need help!

Comment: Robert Green, are you sure you are allowed to pick any $\epsilon$ you wish to? Here you picked $\epsilon = f(x_0)/2$ Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: @Amad27 it is "for all epsilon", by definition of continuity at $x_0$, so I choose epsilon as I want. Honestly, I really advise you to forget your question a bit, as work out elementary continuity $\epsilon,\delta$ stuff, as this are the prerequisites, and as you're apparently really not at all at ease with them. If you do not, you will loose a lot of time.